# (Mono For) Android Emulator Change Virtual Keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin.android, emulation

I would like to change the Emulators Virtual Keyboard.

It looks now like that:

[image]

It should be smth. like that:

[image]

I triet to set the `android:inputType` to text but it didn't work.
I'm also wondering, why there are chinese letters, 
is there a way to set the Location or Land?

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: it not depends on your app it android settings ... got to settings "input & language"(or smth like this it depends on android version on your emulator fx on 1.6 it will be Locale & text) and select keyboard

Comment: where are this android settings?

Comment: have you ever use Android device? .... in apps ... app named "Settings" or localized like "Ustawienia"(pl)  or in home screen menu button=>"Settings"

Comment: I didn't know that u mean, that I should search for the settings on the actual device, yes now it works, thank you.. Post your answer so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in your app ... it's OS settings

You have to lunch "Settings" app and choose keyboard in:

"`Locale & text`" or "`Language & input`" or something similar(depends on android version)

[image: 1.6] [image: 4.1]